# Struggling to perform a simple V-lookup without duplication in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform a V-lookup against two dataframes, which contain the same column. Essentially, I want to lookup df1[x] against df2[x], and if it is present in df2, return a new column in df1['Exists'], or something of this manner. I am trying to do it using pd.merge but I keep running into mass duplication issues: is there any way to resemble the excel version of a v-lookup?

Here is what I am attempting now - is there a better method?

```
df_3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['identifier'], how = 'left', indicator = 'Exist')
df_3['Exist'] = np.where(df_3.Exist == 'both', True, False)
df_3 = df_3[df_3['Exist'] = True]
```

The problem is, when I filter df_3 on 'True', there are thousands of duplicates, which were not present in the original df1. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: there must be duplicated identifiers in your df2.  try dropping those first.

Comment: `df1['Exist'] = df1.identifier.isin(df2.identifier.unique())` might be a better way to do this as well